# How does putting an if statement inside a loop and an else statement outside the loop work together (in python)

Tags: python

```
L=eval(input("Enter a list of elements(number): "))
n=len(L)
print("The original list: ")
print(L)
x=int(input("Enter an element to be searched in the list: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    if L[i]==x:
         print(x," is found at: ",i+1)
         break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

This is a code to search and find an element inside a user given list. This shouldn't be able to work as the else statement is clearly of no use and wrongly indented (with the if statement). A flag would've done the trick but here a flag isn't needed as it manages to work. Can someone explain how?

Comment: The `else:` statement is not related to the `if` statement. It's part of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

An `for`-`else` statement is legit, where the `else` statement only executes if no `break` statement ever got parsed in that `for` loop.

Here is an explanation of the code line-by-line:

1.

```
L=eval(input("Enter a list of elements(number): "))
```

Receive input from the user. The user's input would be taken in as a sting, so using the `eval()` method will evaluate the string as code.

2.

```
n=len(L)
```

The `len()` method takes in an array, and returns the amount of characters in the array.

3.

```
print("The original list: ")
print(L)
```

Display the original list.

4.

```
x=int(input("Enter an element to be searched in the list: "))
```

Receive input from the user, and convert the string to an integer.

5.

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

Loop through the numbers from `0` to `n`, where the `n` is exclusive.

6.

```
    if L[i]==x:
         print(x," is found at: ",i+1)
         break
```

In each iteration, if the `i` index of the array is equal to `x`, display the found message, and use the `break` statement to jump out of the loop.

7.

```
else:
    print("Not found")
```

If the program never met the `break` statement, meaning `x` was never found during the looping, display the not-found message.

---

**Warning:** Using the `eval()` method opens up many security risks, and is extremely dangerous when using it on un-trusted user input.